# How to use getAttribute in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, getattribute

Im using .map to create a small list in an react app

```
{
 this.state.rooms.map((anything, indexPos) =>
   <p className='rooms'
      onClick={this.test}
         key={indexPos}>{anything.name}
   </p>
 )
}
```

The 'test' function that the onClick method calls is as follows:

```
test = (e) => {
 alert();
}
```

My Question is what code do I put inside the '()' of the alert method to alert which specific room was clicked?

It also may help to know what my constructor looks like:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    rooms: [],
    display: 'none',
    newRoomName: 'New room',
    currentRoom: ''
};
  this.roomsRef = this.props.firebase.database().ref('rooms');
}
```

This is a [LINK](https://github.com/DravionV/bloc-chat-react/commit/14ffcfb577532e17cf89c72f6667765e802496ee) to the git files associated with Question.

Being able to alert(); the 'key' attr or index or room name of whichever room I click will then allow me to work on 'rendering' said room selected. Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: e.target.key maybe

Comment: No that gives 'undefined' Jaromanda. Thx though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a single room to your `test` callback. But we have a parameter now, so you need to wrap your function or you'd call immediately `test`, and that's not what you want, you want just to define a callback.

```
{
 this.state.rooms.map((room, indexPos) =>
   <p className='rooms'
      onClick={() => this.test(room)}
         key={indexPos}>{room.name}
   </p>
 )
}
```

Now your callback takes a parameter and you can print some property

```
test = (room) => {
 alert(room.name);
}
```

Comment: WORKS like a charm! now i have to understand why this works... But thanks a million, ill give you green check when the timer alows in six minutes.

Comment: Read this https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html#passing-arguments-to-event-handlers